# Date validation on search input/textbox for a razor view MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, validation

I would like to add a textbox (date) and button to my report, which filters the data.

The below mvc is working, but the input must still be validated (must be a DATE) on client side (and server side if possible)

My Model looks like this :

```
public class DailyReport
{    
    public int DailyReportID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ReportDate { get; set; }
}
```

View :

```
@model IEnumerable<project_name.Models.DailyReport>
@* text box and button:  *@
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "DailyReport", FormMethod.Get))
{   <p>
     Title: @Html.TextBox("SearchDateString")
     <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
     </p>
}
@* display dates*@
@foreach (var item in Model)
{       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReportDate)
}
```

my controller:

```
   public ViewResult Index(String SearchDateString)
    {
        var dailyreport = db.DailyReport.Include(d => d.Site);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchDateString))
        {
            DateTime search_date = Convert.ToDateTime(SearchDateString);
            dailyreport = dailyreport.Where(r => r.ReportDate == search_date);
        }
        return View(dailyreport.ToList());
    }
```

Can someone help me please? 
How do I make sure a valid date is entered in the textbox?
Should I create a another model with a date field for this input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Shark Shark pointed me in the right direction to use a viewmodel, this is the end result that is now working. JS validation added as well.

(DBSet was not necessary because DrViewModel is a viewmodel.)

controllers :

```
    public ActionResult Index(DrViewModel dvm)
    {
        var dailyreport = db.DailyReport.Include(d => d.Site);
        if (dvm.DateTimeSearch != null)
        {
            dailyreport = dailyreport.Where(r => r.ReportDate == dvm.DateTimeSearch);
        }

        dvm.DailyReport = dailyreport.ToList();
        return View(dvm);
    }
```

models :

```
public class DrViewModel
{
    public DateTime? DateTimeSearch { get; set; }
    public List<DailyReport> DailyReport { get; set; }
}

 public class DailyReport
{

    public int DailyReportID { get; set; }
     public DateTime? ReportDate { get; set; }
}
```

view :

```
@model myproject.Models.DrViewModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }

<h2>Index</h2>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript">    </script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"     type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index","DailyReport", FormMethod.Get ))
{   
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

 <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateTimeSearch)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateTimeSearch)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateTimeSearch)
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </div>

}    
   @foreach (var item in Model.DailyReport)
   {
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReportDate)

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Utilize the `DataTypeAttribute` from the `DataAnnotations` namespace in your Model, like so:

```
public class DailyReport
{    
    public int DailyReportID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ReportDate { get; set; }
}

public class DrViewModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public string DateTimeSearch { get; set; }
    List<DailyReport> DailyReports { get; set; }
}
```

In your View, have something like:

```
@model project_name.Models.DrViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "DailyReport", FormMethod.Get))
{   
     <p>
     Title: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateTimeSearch)
     <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
     </p>
}


@foreach (var item in Model.DailyReports)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.ReportDate)
}
```

Comment: Hi Shark. my input-box is not currently referencing the ReportDate directly. It is using the textbox to pass a the string SearchDateString to the controller, which converts it to a Date. How do I validate the SearchDateString input?

Comment: @DavidSmit see my edit.  Use a `TextBoxFor` helper to push it right to the model.  Your validation will occur there.

Comment: Hi Shark
In the view the model is declared as IEnumerable because it is a list. When I add your suggestion I get the error: 

**System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<project_name.Models.DailyReport>' does not contain a definition for 'ReportDate' and no extension method 'ReportDate' accepting a first argument of type**

Comment: @DavidSmit Change your model declaration from `@model IEnumerable<project_name.Models.DailyReport>` to `@model project_name.Models.DailyReport`.  The reason you're getting that error is because your `Model` is of type `IEnumerable<DailyReport>` and there is no `ReportDate` property directly from that.  You'd have to change your `model` declaration or work that that IEnumerable.

Comment: I think it must be an IEnumerable, because I want to display a list of DailyReport. error : **CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'project_name.Models.DailyReport' because 'project_name.Models.DailyReport' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'**

Comment: @DavidSmit See my edit again.  You can use your `foreach` loop, but you'll just have a text box for every item in your model (not sure if that's your desired output).  You're getting that error because you took out the `IEnumerable<T>` as a model.  You can put that back to use the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Not quite what im looking for. I want to display the ReportDate for each DailyReport item, like in my original example. BUT do a date search(filter) on the data. Your example will show me a text box for each DailyReport item

Comment: @DavidSmit then why are you needing validation if you're just displaying data?

Comment: I need DATE validation on the search textbox "SearchDateString", because if they enter text into the textbox which is not a date, the controller will throw an error (I do a select on Date in the controller). Please see my code example in original post

Comment: @DavidSmit Oh, ok.  I'm following now.  See my edit.  You should be using a ViewModel for this.  That is untested code, but should give you the general idea.

Comment: Thanks this is going in the right direction! Do I need to DbSet this as well? (I have DailyReport in a EF database):
public DbSet<DailyReport> DailyReports { get; set; }
public DbSet<DrViewModel> DrViewModel { get; set; } 

** dailyreportview = dailyreportview.Where(r => r.DateTimeSearch == search_date);  Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<project_name.Models.DrViewModel>' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<project_name.Models.DrViewModel>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) **